# Run c program from another one using system gcc command

Tags: c, shell, gcc, command, system

I am trying to run a specific c program from my program using system in c.
gcc tell me "no such file or directory" even if i put the file
in the other program directory. The purpose is to execute the second program if some conditions are reached in the first. any help?

```
if(a==0){
 system(" gcc -g -o iptablesExample mainiptables.c  -lip4tc -lip6tc -ldl ");
                       system(" ./iptablesExample");
}
```

Comment: Does the compilation of `iptablesExample` succeed? Can you find it in the process' current directory? Add a `system("ls");` to see the files in the current directory before you try executing it.

Comment: yes the compilation succeed in the shell, the file was not in the right directory!

Comment: You did not check the returned value of the first `system` command (it should be zero). If you get a zero, the output file for sure exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try your command with execve and fork, but I'm not sure it works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int ac, char **av, char **env) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/ls", "-la", NULL}; //put the absolute path of gcc

  if (pid == 0)
  {
    if (execve(args[0], args, env) == -1)
       perror("error");
  }
  wait(&pid);
  return 0;
}
```

Make sure to put the absolute path

Comment: tks. any example?

Comment: If it doesn't work with `system` it won't start working just by switching to`fork` and `execve`.

Comment: There you have an example, hope it'll work !

Comment: @lilie82 I edited the answer, if it doens't work can you please tell me the message of the perror